# ASP.NET Core 6 Configuration problem with docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a problem with configuration my service with docker. I using VS 2022 to create my server by template "ASP.NET Core Web API". I added two libraries to the solution and they are connected to a main project by reference. Then I used docker plugin to generate "dockerfile" and i get something like this.

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AVM.Core.csproj", "."]
COPY ["../AVM.Domain/AVM.Domain.csproj", "../AVM.Domain/"]
COPY ["../AVM.Repository/AVM.Repository.csproj", "../AVM.Repository/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./AVM.Core.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "AVM.Core.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AVM.Core.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AVM.Core.dll"]
```

I use a sample .dockerignore

```
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
LICENSE
README.md
```

When i try to build my image with command **docker build -t avmcore** i got error like this

```
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 818B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0                                                  0.1s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0                                               0.1s
 => [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0@sha256:84fc4202a1f38fd440b718aeeb4e8cfe046e9f19ef977a28c0  0.0s
 => => resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0@sha256:84fc4202a1f38fd440b718aeeb4e8cfe046e9f19ef977a28c01827d  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.6s
 => => transferring context: 17.69MB                                                                               0.6s
 => [build 1/9] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0@sha256:76dbd63a33da6510787e97c0943c4c4a2136936ce360cf925386  0.0s
 => CACHED [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [final 1/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/9] WORKDIR /src                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/9] COPY [AVM.Core.csproj, .]                                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [build 4/9] COPY [../AVM.Domain/AVM.Domain.csproj, ../AVM.Domain/]                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [build 5/9] COPY [../AVM.Repository/AVM.Repository.csproj, ../AVM.Repository/]                           0.0s
------
 > [build 4/9] COPY [../AVM.Domain/AVM.Domain.csproj, ../AVM.Domain/]:
------
------
 > [build 5/9] COPY [../AVM.Repository/AVM.Repository.csproj, ../AVM.Repository/]:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/AVM.Domain/AVM.Domain.csproj" not found: not found
```

Thanks for all answers guys.

Comment: When you build a docker image, it's done in a 'build context'. This covers the directory the Dockerfile is in and all subdirectories. You're not allowed to access files outside the build context for security reasons. When you try to copy something from `../AVM.Domain` you're trying to move up a directory and go outside the build context. That's not allowed. To solve it, your Dockerfile should move up a directory and you should adjust the file names in the Dockerfile accordingly.

Comment: @HansKilian indeed. I did not know that. Thanks for the help

Comment: @FranczykRafał note that you can set build context outside of the folder which contains the docker file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Visual Studio uses a bit different approach with Docker images.
Try to move to the parent folder where the .sln is and run *docker build* and specify the Dockerfile using the *-f* option.

```
docker build -f ./ProjectFolder/Dockerfile ...
```